# VBA - Set Range for function Based on Header Value

Tags: vba, excel, find, range

Im fairly new to VBA so I need some help with this project I'm working on. I am trying to write a script that is easily scaled and extended so I am avoiding hard code values as much as possible. I also do not want to use any Excel functions in my code. I have a function that calculates the average of a range. And I have a sub that prints the avg to a separate text file. However, I dont want to hard code the range that I need to take the average of. Is it possible to search for the heading (without using Find) and then specify the range of values beneath the heading?

Here is what I have so far. Notice that the range is hard coded in right now. This works perfectly as is but I need it to be more flexible in case the data is not always presented the same way.

```
Function AvgMS(Rng As Range) As Double

    Total = 0
    Count = 0

    For Each cell In Rng

        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

            Total = Total + cell.Value
            Count = Count + 1

        End If

    Next cell

    AvgMS = Total / Count

End Function

Sub Average() 'Generate CSV File

  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim AMS As Double

  'Directory Address
  FilePath1 = "Macintosh HD:Users:Me:Documents:Project:avg.csv"
  FileNum = FreeFile

  Open FilePath1 For Output As #FileNum

  AMS = AvgMS(Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))) 'Define Data Range for AvgMS Function

  Print #FileNum, AMS ' Print text to file.

  Close #FileNum ' Close file.

  MsgBox ("avg.csv successfully updated")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to search for the text "Header" in the "used range" of "Sheet1":

```
Function FindFirstOccurrence(FindString As String) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
            Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set FindFirstOccurrence = rng
            Else
                Set FindFirstOccurrence = Nothing
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = FindFirstOccurrence("Header")
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rng.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm hoping you can adapt it to your requirements but let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. This looks good but it is throwing an error and saying object required. Something to do with the `Set FindFirstOccurrence = vbNothing` part.

Comment: @DillonMcDonald: Sorry, was in a rush and didn't check properly. Please check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this simple solution and it works. Any issues seen with this?

```
   'Find column where the  data is located and set range
    i = 1
    Do Until Cells(1, i) = "Text"
    i = i + 1
    Loop

    CellNum = Cells(1, i).Offset(1, 0).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

    'Set the range for AMS Function
    Set MSrng = Range(CellNum, Range(CellNum).End(xlDown))l
```

Comment: A couple of issues, yes. (1) Your Loop around `i` never ends if "Text" is not found. (2) What if the text you're trying to find is in a row *other than* row 1? You never said in your question that it must always be found in row 1. What was wrong with the code I posted in my answer?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. Your code actually worked perfectly. I was also able to modify it to set the range below it. (See code below) But my goal with this project is to only use VBA code and no Excel functions. Is .Find not an excel function?

Comment: This particular [`Find` function (link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.14).aspx) is a method of the `Range` object, so not an Excel function.

Comment: Oh. Ok then that would work fine. Thank you again for the clarification. I was able to do what I needed by just changinge this part... `rng1 = rng.Offset(1, 0).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)`